# How to change avast firewall settings to allow maven to download required plugins?

Tags: java, maven

When i run

```
> mvn archetype:generate
```

i get following error:

```
    mvn archetype:generate
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
    [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.79.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 03:12 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-13T12:48:22+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/77M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Arun\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I am using Avast Internet Security 2016 in windows 7 OS and trying to use apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.
Avast is handling firewall settings and maven needs to configure/disbale firewall settings so that maven can download required plugins.

```
I came to know that one of its solution is to configure maven settings.xml
```

But I want to know how to configure avast to allow maven to download required things.

What I tried:

- From the main Avast window went to Firewall section.
- Next, Clicked on "Application Rules".
- Selected "New Group" and named it as Maven.
- Now clicked on "New Application Rule", selected Maven and added mvn and mvn.cmd files from the apache-maven-3.3.9/bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved:

- Open avast firewall setting and turn it off.
- Now use maven and it will download the required dependencies.
- Turn on firewall from avast settings when maven downloading is finished.
- Because dependencies are downloaded you will not have any problem
  with maven.

If someone has better solution please share.
Thanks in advance..